# Insert unique identifier foreign key into table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I’m attempting to insert dummy search data using statements like this (the values differ for each one):

```
insert into SEARCHRESULTEXTENSIONBASE
    (CAL_ISBN, CAL_SEARCHRESULTID, USAGEDATAIMPORTID)
    VALUES('9780347011266', '1317168818', '925e3a5e-e971-11e0-9425-00219b71cde3')
```

But I’m getting this error:

```
[SQL Server] Conversion failed when converting from a character string
             to uniqueidentifier.
```

The field USAGEDATAIMORTID is a uniqueidentifier field, and I'm using similar statements in another table which successfully accepts the data:

```
INSERT INTO IMPORTUNIVERSITY
    (USAGEDATAIMPORTID, PAGENUMBERS, PUBLISHERNAME, RECORDID, DEPARTMENTNAME) 
    VALUES('925e3a5e-e971-11e0-9425-00219b71cde3', '2',
            'Nationwide News Pty Limited',
             '74', 'Business');
```

The only difference that I can see is the `SEARCHRESULTEXTENSIONBASE` table `USAGEDATAIMPORTID` is a foreign key to the `IMPORTUNIVERSITY` table.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

```
insert into SEARCHRESULTEXTENSIONBASE
            (CAL_ISBN, CAL_SEARCHRESULTID, USAGEDATAIMPORTID)
            VALUES('06463322521', '1317173481', convert(uniqueidentifier,'925e3a5e-e971-11e0-9425-00219b71cde3'))
```

gives me the same error.

Comment: Are you sure that's a valid UUID?  Try typecasting it as below.

Comment: Fixed that, just a mistake whilst putting the question together :)

Comment: Do you have a trigger on the table? Or a complex check constraint?

Comment: -1 for incomplete and incorrect question: OP's self answer below demonstrates an issue unrelated to FKs

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
insert into SEARCHRESULTEXTENSIONBASE             
(CAL_ISBN, CAL_SEARCHRESULTID, USAGEDATAIMPORTID)             
VALUES('9780347011266', '1317168818', 
convert(uniqueidentifier, 'b6c51461-e966-11e0-b87a-0219b71cde3'))
```

You need to convert your string to the `uniqueidentifier` datatype.

Comment: Then I believe the reason for that would be your `uniqueidentifier` string is not in the right format.

Comment: @danpants: "Ah but the very same string is accepted in another table" -> this must be wrong then?

Answer (score 0):

You have one less digit in the GUID you are using. Could be a copy paste error.

```
b6c51461-e966-11e0-b87a-0219b71cde3 - has 31 digits
F567D3BC-45E9-4891-A0FB-BDE143236867 - should have 32 digits (correct)
```

You can test it as

```
SELECT Cast('b6c51461-e966-11e0-b87a-0219b71cde3' as UniqueIdentifier)
```

throws

```
Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
```

while

```
SELECT Cast('F567D3BC-45E9-4891-A0FB-BDE143236867' as UniqueIdentifier)
```

works fine.

Comment: Post the definition of both tables (including any FKs)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like CAL_ISBN or CAL_SEARCHRESULTID is uniqueidentifier and you are trying to insert a character string instead. Could you please provide schema definition of the table you are inserting to and getting a error.

Comment: Nope CAL_ISBN and CAL_SEARCHRESULTID are both INTEGER fields, USAGEDATAIMPORT is the only UNIQUEIDENTIFIER.

Comment: SELECT Cast('925e3a5e-e971-11e0-9425-00219b71cde3' as UniqueIdentifier) works fine, so the value itself is definately ok.

Comment: Could you please provide schema definition of the table you are inserting to and getting a error.

Comment: Another good idea would be to create a minimal repro, so that SO members can see the problem for themselves. Chances are, though that you'll solve you problem why creating the repro, so this is a win-win.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by there being no matching UUIDs in the two tables, thus the foreign key relationship failed.  Would've been easier to work out if the error message wasn't so misleading.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The error message would be different if there was no parent row. It isn't misleading. This means maybe you don't have an FK because you have different data types: but no matching GUID does not give this error